# MongoDB/PostgreSQL:hstore vs EAV

Tags: mongodb, yii2, postgresql, hstore, eav

Ищу решение для нового проекта. Необходимо хранить произвольный набор заранее неопределенных параметров (Даты, числа, строки). Сначала присматривался к [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), но как-то мне это решение не симпатизирует. Поэтому сейчас в основном рассматриваю варианты MongoDB/PostgreSQL:hstore.

По параметрам желательно иметь возможность быстро сортировать (для миллионов позиций и десятков миллионов параметров). В pg это особых проблем вызвать не должно, в монго, думаю, тоже.

Остался вопрос удобства работы с динамическим набором параметров и их валидации в yii2. Для работы с hstore в yii2 ничего не нашел, не могу предугадать возможные проблемы, про Active Record можно будет забыть? Не возникнет проблем с представлением? Что касаемо MongoDB, до этого им не пользовался поэтому и тут подводных камней пока не вижу. Может, будут какие-то общие рекомендации?

Answer (score 2):

В PostgreSQL (начиная с 9.4 версии) обратите внимание на новый тип данных - jsonb (здесь можно почитать - [тип json](http://postgrespro.ru/doc/datatype-json.html))
Этот тип индексируется и эффективно ищется по различным его составляющим.
Может хранить внутри вложенные иерархические данные разного содержания.
Пока на данные момент (версия 9.4) нет удобного синтаксиса для модификации части содержимого (но работы идут :) ). Требуется полный разбор с последующим сбором всех подчастей.